# How to delete rows with specific values in a (frequency) table in R?

Tags: r, delete-row

With `mytable <- table(VarA, varB)` I've created a frequency table that looks like this:

```
     1  2
0    0  5
1    5  7
2    0  0
3    7  9
4    0  0
5    5 10
```

Now I want to run some statistics with `assocstats` and `table2d_summary` on that table. But first I want to delete the empty values. That means the rows in the table with zero counts,

So how can I get rid of the rows with both frequencies of 0 (in my example it's row 2 and 4)?

For a data frame I could just use the `subset`function:

```
mytable_noZ <- subset(mytbale, mytable$VarA != 0 & mytable$VarB != 0)
```

But it doesn't seem to be possible to refer to a variable (a column) by this method in a table.

A way that worked was deleting the rows "manually"

```
mytable_noZ <- mytable[-c(2,4),]
```

Which is easy in this example but I've some bigger tables.

I searched for a solution here and elsewhere but always only found ways to delete rows, variables and cases in data frames.

So hopefully someone can help me on this.

Comment: You can convert it to a data.frame with `mytablenew <- as.data.frame.matrix(mytable)` and then do the `subset` as you showed

Comment: Thanks! That was helpfull.

Comment: I had tried this way but only with `as.data.frame(mytable)`. Which gave me a data frame with case counts. Now I'm stuck in converting my data frame back into a table (which is necessary for the `assocstats`function). I tried to convert with `as.table(mytbalenew)`. But it just says it can't convert.

Comment: another possibility would be to drop the levels from you VarA, that don't appear in your data. Then you don't get the all-zero-lines from the beginning.

Comment: That would also be an idea but seems to me the more complicated way. Since I first need to find out which are the levels of VarA which don't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my question and want to present it here. Just in case someone else comes across this problem.

First I transformed the table into a data.frame (like akrun suggested):

```
mydf <- as.data.frame.matrix(mytable)
```

Then I chose the rows to drop and saved it into the variable `deleterows` and used this variable to delete the rows from the original table:

```
deleterows <- which(mydf$`1` == 0 & mydf$`2` == 0)
mytable <- mytable[-deleterows,]
```